# "doing sports" or "when doing sports"

Tags: writing-style

I came across the following sentence:

"Appropriate equipment and being focused on training are always the most vital aspects when doing sports"

My question is: Is "when" necessary here? Can I just say "...vital aspects doing sports" ?

Comment: "...when *engaging in sports*" might be better. Generally, one doesn't "do" sports, but rather "plays," "watches," "participates in" or "engages in" sports. "Doing sports" just sounds awkward to my American English ear.

Comment: I'd add "having" at the start to match "being".

Comment: "When" is probably not the best word either: presumably you want to get equipment and training *before* doing sports.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *when* is necessary to communicate that the statement applies at times when sport is "being done" (presumably by an individual).

> "...vital aspects doing sports"

This would make *aspects* the subject, ie. you'd be stating that the "aspects" themselves are engaging in a sporting activity. This of course does not make sense.